# ROS Remap topic doesn't work - Multiple Robots

Tags: xml, ros, launch, robotics, robot

Based on the tutorial [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/), I tried to create my launches to run multiple robots in gazebo. 
Each robot has a node [called stopper] that takes care to move it. I want that each robot will move separately, so I will publish to {robot_name}/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop topic.

when running "rostopic info /cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop" I noticed that I have only mobile_base_nodelet_manager as subscriber, with no publisher (the publisher exists into  {robot_name}/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop topic.
Therefore, I used remap but it still doesn't work and the same problem appears.

**one_robot.lanuch**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch> 

   <arg name="robot_name"/>
   <arg name="init_pose"/>

   <node name="spawn_minibot_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"
     args="$(arg init_pose) -urdf -param /robot_description -model $(arg robot_name)"
    respawn="false" output="screen" />

    <!-- Launch stopper node -->
    <node name="stopper" pkg="stopper" type="stopper" output="screen" args="$(arg robot_name)">
     <remap from="scan" to="$(arg robot_name)/scan"/>
     <remap from="cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop" to="$(arg robot_name)/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop"/>

    </node>
</launch>
```

**robots.launch**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <!-- No namespace here as we will share this description. 
         Access with slash at the beginning -->
  <param name="robot_description"
          command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find turtlebot_description)/robots/kobuki_hexagons_asus_xtion_pro.urdf.xacro"/>

 <!-- BEGIN ROBOT 1-->
 <group ns="robot1">
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="robot1_tf" />
    <include file="$(find stopper)/launch/one_robot.launch" >
      <arg name="init_pose" value="-x 1 -y 1 -z 0" />
      <arg name="robot_name"  value="Robot1" />
    </include>
 </group>

 <!-- BEGIN ROBOT 2-->
 <group ns="robot2">
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="robot2_tf" />
   <include file="$(find stopper)/launch/one_robot.launch" >
     <arg name="init_pose" value="-x -1 -y 1 -z 0" />
     <arg name="robot_name"  value="Robot2" />
   </include>
 </group>
</launch>
```

**multiple_robots.launch**

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <launch>
      <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />

      <!-- include our robots -->
      <include file="$(find stopper)/launch/robots.launch"/>

      <!-- start world -->
      <include file="$(find turtlebot_gazebo)/launch/turtlebot_world.launch"/>       
   </launch>
```

- As it looks, I tried to remap in one_robot.launch, but it still didn't work as I mentioned previous. 
  I notice that the remap works only if I do it in `multiple_robots.launch`, but it's not really possible for me, because there we don't know the robot names, but just in `one_robot.launch`.

I would like to get your help to solve this issue, I spent a lot of time on this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

is an option for a given node.  Thus I believe it needs to be added under a node tag.  So it has to be within the `<node> ... </node>` block.

Additionally, what you are trying to do could be achieved by launching your teleop nodes under appropriate namespace, either using the  `<group ns="XXX">` in a launch file or in the terminal by running `export ROS_NAMESPACE=XXX` before launching the teleop node.

Comment: I added remap under <node> ... </node>  but it still doesn't work and has the problem as I described previous. Do you have an idea? Thank you.

Comment: Updated. I would like to get your help.

Comment: Try running rostopic info and echo to see which topic stopper is publishing to.

Comment: I have two stopper's instances (one for each robot). The first one publishes to robot1/robot1/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop and the second to robot2/robot2/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop. However, no subscribers at all to the above topics - and that's the reason I tried to use 'remap', but it doesn't work for me. /mobile_base_nodelet_manager subscribers to /cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop topic.

Comment: You want to be publishing to robot1/... not robot1/robot1/...  so you need is picking up the namespace from somewhere.

Comment: I don't think it matters, it is just a name. Even if I were publishing to "robot1/.." my problem still existed. The problem is that I publish to "robot1/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop" but no subscriber exists (there is subscriber just to "cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop"). I tried to use 'remap' for this, but still doesn't work (as I described in my post)

Comment: Then it sounds like the stopper node is working as expected. Issue is with the other nodes. Your multiple_robots.launch is launching turtlebot_world.launch while one_robot.launch is launching a spawn_model node. So what's in your turtlebot_world.launch?

Comment: turtlebot_world.launch is not a launch that I wrote myself, but one of turtlebot_gazebo. My code can be found here: https://github.com/Ofir408/Stopper/tree/launches_problem

Answer (score 0):

When you say this, it makes me think remap is working:

> when running "rostopic info /cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop" I noticed that I have only mobile_base_nodelet_manager as subscriber, with no publisher (the publisher exists into {robot_name}/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop topic.

The old topic `/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop` doesn't have a publisher anymore, which would be true if remap worked. And you say the publisher exists for the remapped topic, `{robot_name}/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop` that means the remap is working.

You say `mobile_base_nodelet_manager` is subscribing to the old topic, but it should be subscribing to the new topic. Remap doesn't change the topic for both publishers and subscribers. Remap isn't global.

I would make sure the nodes that were subscribing to the old topic, are now subscribing to the new topic.  You'll have to do a remap on the Subscribers too, so they know what the new topic is and that they can subscribe to it.

The ROS docs describe remapping on a subscriber node: [Remap Docs](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap)

Comment: thank you. Regarding to "{robot_name}/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop" publisher, it exists because I publish to this topic in my code (no remap for this). In addition, I agree that I have to do "remap" to my subscribers. However, that problem still exists, because as I wrote, if I do remap in one_robot.lanuch, the remap actually doesn't work (and I don't know why). I tried to remap also within <node>...<node> (doesn't work) and also after the line "   <arg name="init_pose"/>". Both in one_robot.launch and the remap doesn't work. Any Idea? Thanks.

Comment: Try moving the remap to `robots.launch`. I have a feeling that the `group` tags and the separate namespaces are causing trouble. There's also a remap attribute for group tags you may want to try. <group> tag docs: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/group

Comment: putting 'remap' in robot.launch is working for the publishers, but I still haven't subscribers. I want each robot will have a publisher to "{robot_name}/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop, and {robot_name}/mobile_base_nodelet_manager as a subscriber, but I haven't this subscriber at all.  Maybe can you show me how can I achieve this? I'm not sure how should I do the 'remap' for this subscriber, this is a class that was written by ros.

Comment: Edit the launch file that's launching the subscriber node and do a remap there. Or duplicate the old launch file that's opening the subscriber node and modify it with the `remap` tag and call the your new launch file instead of the old one.